# Kendo not working with jQuery 2.0?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

It seems that Kendo UI web does not work with jQuery 2.0.0.  I saw a problem in my app after updating.  The grid defaults to even width columns, the width value is no longer used.

To confirm that it was not something in my app, I took the default index.html file from the examples (or [Kendo UI Grid Sample](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html)) and updated the reference jQuery.min.js to jQuery-2.0.0-min.js and the same problem exists.

I guess I am stuck with jQuery 1.9 for now, just wondering if anyone else is seeing this and if there is a fix or workaround I can apply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an up-to-date version of Kendo UI to get jQuery 2.0 support.

Comment: I am doing this project at home (not for profit), so the only version I have access to is the free one and that only gets released a few times a year.  So if there is an up-to-date version, you have to pay to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to be using internet explorer ? Jquery 2.0 is the same as 1.9 the only difference is that they dont provide implementations for IE (at least for 8 and below, check out this [link](http://jquery.com/browser-support/).

Comment: So why do you want to use jquery 1.9 over 2.0 ? Is see the link I posted they are exactly the same except for the IE support

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but it doesn't look like anyone has pointed out the link to Kendo's answer:
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies

```
The current official version of Kendo UI requires jQuery 1.9.1. There are occasions in which a new jQuery version is released, which introduces breaking changes and is not compatible with existing Kendo UI versions. In such cases we recommend using the previous jQuery version until the next official Kendo UI release that resolves the problems. We normally do not change the jQuery version that is shipped with Kendo UI for service packs. We can do this for major releases. The following list provides compatibility information about previous major Kendo UI releases:
Kendo UI 2013.3.1119 (Q3 2013) - jQuery 1.9.1 (works also with 1.10.x and 2.0.x)
Kendo UI 2013.2.716 (Q2 2013) - jQuery 1.9.1
Kendo UI 2013.1.319 (Q1 2013) - jQuery 1.9.1
Kendo UI 2012.3.1114 (Q3 2012) - jQuery 1.8.2
Kendo UI 2012.2.710 (Q2 2012) - jQuery 1.7.1
Kendo UI 2012.1.322 (Q1 2012) - jQuery 1.7.1
Kendo UI 2011.3.1129 (Q3 2011) - jQuery 1.7.1
There should be no problem to use another minor jQuery version instead of the specified above, e.g. 1.7.2 instead of 1.7.1.
```

Comment: Yes.  Looks like the latest version of Kendo works with 2.x.  Had to wait 6 months though.